# PHP Restrict access to users of specific location

Tags: php, security, ip

I'm being asked to prevent users from accessing a site if their ips doesn't match a provided list of ips saved in a database. The idea being for instance to allow all people in a shool for instance to access the site - but only them.

Checking the IP sounds like a good idea, however what about dynamic ips? A set list won't work then, and security-wise I'm sure it's pretty straightforward to simulate a fake ip.

That doesn't sound like a very reliable solution. What is the proper way to do this? I'm thinking maybe checking a key on the local machine or something? Simple way to do this in php?

Comment: What about a kind of permission for users registrated in your site?

Comment: `What is the proper way to do this?` I would use the server to do this. This can easily be accomplished with access rules on your web server.  Then you can make it like an intranet and only allow internal IP address or the range.

Comment: Panama Jack: yes or stored in a db. But what if the ips change? (in case of dynamic ips for instance)

Comment: I wouldn't do it via IP, as you mention the IP's change if they're dynamic. Why not just set up a login page and add say accesslevels?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. Once because your concerns or because we can use fake IPs thorough some proxies or other methods. The most modern way to do the authentication and authorization is oAuth2, that is an architectural model who use a token for authorisation. Simplistic, the the user will use a password to authenticate and the server will send back an token (there are three methods here...). The user will store the token in his session and thus he will be authorize to access only his "level" properties but not re-authenticate ...

Comment: you can't fake an IP for TCP, unless you have control over the routers between the attacker and target. You can only MASK the IP via proxies

Comment: I see for oAuth2 but I cannot use a simple login with password even with oAuth2 because students for instance would give away the password. They must request the site from a specific location (within the school or from allowed computers only) Basically like an intranet.

Comment: Without authentication you can never know who is accessing your information. That same student that would give or sell his password could almost as easily set up an SSH server on his laptop that a 3rd party can use to suck all your data out with it appearing to you as the school's IP.

Comment: Yes I you are right, IPs are not the way to do this. So how can it be done then? because the client's request is quite legitimate. Is it impossible to restrict access to a group of users in a specific location (say a school) to access a website? Without a user/password combination (as users could give it away...)

Answer (score 0):

get the users longitude and latitude using position.coords.latitude()  in javascript the and get the max and min longitude and latitude of the target area
use if functions to display an alert (error) window.
this done using frontend.
for more read about HTML GEOLOCATION APIs on